# Need help writing an Angular TypeScript Jasmine test for an Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to write a test for an Angular Service using TypeScript. I'll be honest and say I have no idea what I'm doing as this is the first test I have ever written so any help would be appreciated.

What I have so far gives the following error:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.httpAccessor.get(requestUrl).then')

Here is the service I am attempting to test:

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/_references.ts" />

module app.service {
  'use strict';

  export interface IAvailability {
    getAvailability(requirements: app.Requirements): ng.IPromise<any>;
  }

  export class Availability implements IAvailability {

    static $inject = ['$filter', 'Service.HttpResourceAccessor'];

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    constructor(private $filter: ng.IFilterService,
      private httpAccessor: app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor) {
    }   

    /**
     *  Returns availability promise
     */
    getAvailability(requirements: app.Requirements): ng.IPromise<any> {

      /**
      * Generate the request url using the requirements
      */
      var requestUrl = this.generateRequestUrlFromRequirements(requirements);

      return this.httpAccessor.get(requestUrl).then((response) => {

        var availability: app.ITripAvailability<app.ITripAvailability>response;
        return availability;
      });
    }

    /**
    * Builds the request url using the requirements
    */
    private generateRequestUrlFromRequirements(requirements: app.Requirements): string {

      //The request string that will be returned after building
      var requestUrl: string = '';
      var baseAddress = 'http://localhost:8080/';

      //Code emitted as this just builds a string and works fine

      return requestUrl;
    }
  }

  angular.module('app.service')
    .service('Service.Availability', Availability);
}
```

Here is the test so far:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/_references.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

module app.service {

  describe("app.service.IAvailability", () => {
    'use strict';

    var $filter: ng.IFilterService;
    var mockAvailabilityService: app.service.Availability;
    var mockHttpAccessor: app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor;
    var requirements: app.Requirements;

    beforeEach(() => {
      angular.mock.module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
      angular.mock.module('app.service');
    });

    /**
    * Pre-test function before the test is executed
    */
    beforeEach(() => {

      requirements = new app.Requirements();

      angular.mock.inject((_$filter_: ng.IFilterService) => {
        $filter = _$filter_;

        mockHttpAccessor = <app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor>jasmine.createSpyObj(
          "httpAccessor", ["get"]);

        mockAvailabilityService = new app.service.Availability(
          <ng.IFilterService>$filter, 
          <app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor>mockHttpAccessor);
      });

    });

    it('Should call httpAccessor.get', () => {
      mockAvailabilityService.getAvailability(tripRequirements);
      expect(mockHttpAccessor.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    //How do I check if promise has been resolved?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are heading in the right direction...

```
describe('app.service.IAvailability', ()=>{
  // declare dependencies and common vars
  var mockFilter: ng.IFilterService,
    mockHttpAccessor: app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor,
    requirements: app.Requirements,
    availabilityService: app.service.Availability;

  // setup dependencies/mocks
  beforeEach(()=>{
    angular.mock.module('app');
    angular.mock.inject((_$filter_: ng.IFilterService) => {
      mockFilter = _$filter_;
    });
    mockHttpAccessor = <app.service.IHttpResourceAccessor>jasmine.createSpyObj("httpAccessor", ["get"]); 
  });

  // helper function to create instance of the service
  // (useful if dependencies change, only 1 function needs changed)
  function createService(){
    availabilityService = new app.service.Availability(
      mockFilter,
      mockHttpAccessor);
  }

  // not a great test, but shows how to use the setup above
  it('should contain a getAvailability method', () => {
    createService();
    expect(availabilityService. getAvailability).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. But how would I call the actual method and see if it works? I have edited the question to show what I have tried.

Comment: After you call `createService` then `availabilityService` is an instance of your service and you can call whatever method on it, or access any other properties it has as well, depending on what you're testing.

Comment: the get method is a spy, so you can `expect(mockHttpAccessor.get).toHaveBeenCalled()` or for more granularity use `toHaveBeenCalledWith` to check the params it was called with

Comment: I tried that. It gives an error: Expected spy httpAccessor.get to have been called.

Comment: You first need to call `availabilityService.getAvailability` which in turn will call your mock `get` method, then you verify that it was called.